# Convert Blob to Image file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, blob

I have tried to convert blobs to image file using the below code.

```
var file = new File([blobs],"Download.png");
```

This gives me a file with type null

**This is my file in console.**

```
lastModified: 1618930293005
lastModifiedDate: Tue Apr 20 2021 07:51:33 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) {}
name: "Download.png"
size: 3
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

While I'm trying to download this file, it is downloading as a text file and not an image file. Can somebody help me with this?

I want to download the original file (i.e., Image file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show image from blob in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478863/show-image-from-blob-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the type in the third parameter:

```
 new File([blobs], "Download.png", { type: "image/png" })
```